# RemoteWebdriver started with PhantomJS does not open https url

Tags: java, https, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am using selenium with PhantomJs to scrape the URL. I initialized the driver as below

```
final DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
caps.setCapability(
        PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
        "PhantomJsPath");
caps.setCapability("page.settings.loadImages", false);
caps.setCapability("trustAllSSLCertificates", true);

RemoteWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
driver.setLogLevel(Level.OFF);
driver.get("https://.......")
```

The pagesource obtained from the driver is empty

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Selenium is a poor choice for web scraping. Have you looked at something like curl or httpbuilder?

Comment: I need to submit the form and do Javascript changes . so I preferred Selenium. Could you find to work it to scrape https url. I think the url i am gonna scrape has some unknown certificates and thus it is not scraping. We have to set parameter to ignore SSL params. I could not get the correct params

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recently the POODLE vulnerability forced websites to remove SSLv3 support. Since PhantomJS < v1.9.8 uses SSLv3 by default, the page cannot be loaded. To fix this, you would need to run PhantomJS with `--ssl-protocol=tlsv1` or `--ssl-protocol=any`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26417660/1816580) for plain PhantomJS.

```
caps = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs(); // or new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, 
        new String[] {"--ssl-protocol=tlsv1"});
// other capabilities
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

If this doesn't solve the issue, you can also add

```
"--web-security=false", "--ignore-ssl-errors=true"
```

to the String array of cli args as seen in SiKing's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24415508).

Comment: --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 works for me. I tried with the latter but doesn't work