# Phantomjs driver: get url not working for https

Tags: java, selenium, automation, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I'm using phantomJS driver to automate some tests. On the home page if I get a webElement and output the href I can copy it to a browser and the page opens but in the test when I do driver.get(loginLink.getAttribute("href")) it just stays on the same page.

It works fine on the live site but not on our internal staging site.

I've added 
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);

but I still can't open the login page. Please can anybody suggest what can be causing this?

Update:
More testing I've found it's only https pages that wont load

Comment: driver.get(loginLink.getAttribute("href")) , you mean it should redirect you to on another page?

Comment: Yes. I'm outputting loginLink.getAttribute("href") and if I copy the output into a browser it works fine but the driver.get is just staying on the home page. I'm guessing it's something to do with security because it works fine on the live site

Comment: did you try to fine exact issue by putting try/catch?

Comment: When I do driver.get I take a screenshot and it's just black I then try to access an element which throws an error because the element isn't found. No error is thrown from the actual driver.get

Comment: Ok I've found it's only https pages that are not loading through the driver

Comment: @user2239784 Please, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26604617/2715393

Comment: Thank you! I had already seen that answer but stupid me was setting PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS 3 times instead of all in one so I was obviously clearing whichever one fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

phantomjs defaults to SSL 3.0 when using https. Since SSL 3.0 is disabled on lots of hosts because it is insecure, the SSL handshake will fail. Use phantomjs `--ignore-ssl-errors=true`, `--web-security=false`,  `--ssl-protocol=any` to make phantomjs use a more modern version (TLS1.0 or higher).

phantomJS uses different mechanism in setting capabilities

```
static ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<String>();
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
cliArgsCap.add("--web-security=false");
cliArgsCap.add("--ssl-protocol=any");
cliArgsCap.add("--ignore-ssl-errors=true");
capabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
capabilities.setCapability(
    PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCap);
capabilities.setCapability(
    PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_CLI_ARGS,
        new String[] { "--logLevel=2" });
this.driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
```

Hope it will help :)